# Where did all these untracked files come from?

Tags: git, github, git-untracked

$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    ../.android/
    ../.bash_history
    ../.bash_profile
    ../.bashrc
    ../.gitconfig
    ../.lmmsrc.xml
    ../.viminfo
    ../3D Objects/
    ../AppData/
    ../Contacts/
    Books/
    Brackets.lnk
    Coding Projects/
    Dannys UNI/
    Game Dev/
    HP/
    Learning Dutch.odt
    Photoshop - Shortcut.lnk
    Photoshop/
    Repository/
    Repository2/
    SCAN0000.bmp
    Spotify.lnk
    Steam.lnk
    Studies/
    Stuff I Dont Want To Sort/
    Sublime Text 3.lnk
    desktop.ini
    game_new.js
    game_old.js
    meme_salt_bae-20170206-007-rita.jpg
    ~$Oober.odt
    ~$e situation in yemen.docx
    ~$linese.docx
    ~WRL4078.tmp
    ../Documents/
    ../Downloads/
    ../Favorites/
    ../Links/
    ../Music/
    ../NTUSER.DAT
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2c-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2c-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2c-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2c-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TxR.blf
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2d-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TM.blf
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2d-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TMContainer000000000                                                                                                                                                                                               00000000001.regtrans-ms
    ../NTUSER.DAT{48f83f2d-82db-11e6-b460-dfd6d497f2b5}.TMContainer000000000                                                                                                                                                                                               00000000002.regtrans-ms
    ../OneDrive/
    ../Pictures/
    ../Saved Games/
    ../Searches/
    ../Videos/
    ../ntuser.dat.LOG1
    ../ntuser.dat.LOG2
    ../ntuser.ini
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

#### Where did all these untracked files come from?

Could someone please help me out, not too sure why all these untracked files are here.

All I did was create aliases for sublime and Brackets (subl & brac) and put them in .bashrc, now whenever I use git status all these untracked files add up.

I've only started learning and seem to have already not something wrong!

Comment: What folder are you in?

Comment: danny@Home MINGW64 ~/Desktop (master)


On Desktop, every single directory I go to this pops up.

Comment: It looks like you somehow `git init`ed your `~/Desktop` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you setup a git repository in your user folder. There should be a `.git` folder in your user directory. Remove that folder to stop tracking the user folder.

Comment: Yes! Thank you buddy!

Comment: If this fixed you're issue, would you be able to mark this as the answer?